# does ModelAndView from Spring MVC have an equivalent in Play framework

Tags: playframework, java-ee-7

does ModelAndView have a direct equivalent in Play framework, and if not how could I recreate SpringMVC code in Play that uses this class, is their some simple code that could do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in the sense that you have a single container like ModelAndView. The purpose of ModelAndView (which is basically a `Map<String, Object>`) is mostly to have a single container where you put all your data that is used in the template later on and give each of those data pieces a name.
In Play you just give your template all your objects for your template directly.

An example in Play could look like:

```
public Result index() {
  // Somehow instantiate anObject and anotherObject
  return ok(views.html.Controller.index(anObject, anotherObject));
}
```

And your template `index.html.scala` would start with the following:

```
@(anObject: AnObjectType, anotherObject: AnotherObjectType)
```